# If y' is positive at a value of x, then y is increasing there. Is the converse true?

Tags: calculus

I know it's a dumb question, but I really don't know it. I've thought of the derivative of y = x but it's still positive and the book says the answer is no.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First a monotonic function is derivable almost everywhere. So if you add a continuity hypothesis around $x_0$ then you'll get the derivability in $x_0$.

From there $f'(x_0)=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\underbrace{\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}}_{>0\text{ by strict increasing}}\ge 0$

So even if you consider strict monotonicity, the inequality will become loose by limit operation.

So the converse may not be true:

- because the function is not continuous in $x_0$, e.g. $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$, it is increasing but $f'(1)$ is not defined for instance since it has different values on the left and on the right of $x_0=1$.
- because the derivative is zero and not strictly positive, e.g $f(x)=\operatorname{sgn}(x)\ e^{-1/x^2}$ whose all n-derivatives in $0$ are zero.

Anyway, if you consider the function locally continuous around $x_0$ and positive in a loose sense, then the converse is true.

Answer (score 1):

The question deals with a function $y=f(x) $ if $x$ and it's behavior at a specific point $x$.

It is better to use a different symbol $c$ to represent the specific point. So let the derivative $y'=f'(x) $ at $x=c$ be positive ie $f'(c) >0$. Since $$f'(c) =\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$$ it follows that the fraction under above limit is positive for all sufficiently small values of $h$. This means that $f(c+h) - f(c) $ has same sign as that of $h$. Let's take $h>0$ then it means that $f(c+h) >f(c) $. If $h<0$, say $h=-k,k>0$, then $f(c+h) =f(c-k) <f(c) $.

The above conclusion can be worded in the following manner. *If $f'(c) >0$ then there is an open interval $I$ with $c\in I$ such that if $x\in I, x<c$ then $f(x) < f(c) $ and if $x\in I, x>c$ then $f(x) >f(c) $*. This behavior is expressed more concisely as *$f$ is strictly increasing at point $c$*. It **does not mean** that $f$ is strictly increasing in some interval like $I$ containing $c$.

On the other hand the converse does not hold true. In other words if $f$ is strictly increasing at point $c$ and $f'(c) $ exists then it *does not necessarily* imply that $f'(c) >0$. One can only conclude $f'(c) \geq 0$. An example is $f(x) =x^3$ and $c=0$. Convince yourself that $f$ is strictly increasing at $0$ but $f'(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the converse is true, at least if your function is sufficiently "nice" (i.e. differentiable). The derivative is just the gradient of the function, so if the derivative is positive, then so is the gradient, and the function increases. But if the derivative doesn't exist (i.e. the function is not differentiable), then even if it *seems* to be increasing on some interval based on, say, its graph, its derivative would not be positive because it doesn't exist. For example, look at the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

Comment: That's odd, I have like 3 more exercises asking me to proof related stuff. For example: Show by exhibiting curves representing functions that if y = f(x) increases at each value of x of some interval (a,b) that f'(x) is not necessarily an increasing function.

Comment: that is not the same. e.g. $f'(x)=1/x$ is decreasing on $\mathbb R^{+*}$ yet $f(x)=\ln(x)$ is an increasing function. $f'$ sign and $f'$ monotonicity are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R, x\longmapsto x^3$.

$f$ is strictly increasing, namely $f(x_0)<f(x_1)$ whenever $x_0<x_1$, and this even at the origin,
but $f'(0)$ is ...

Comment: Good point, but f(x) isn't increasing at the origin, graph it and you will see a line, the derivative being 0 agrees with that. The function is strictly increasing everywhere but the origin.

Comment: This is at the heart of the question! It's good to write down the definition of "strictly increasing", namely $f(x_0) <f(x_1)$ whenever $x_0 <x_1$. This property *is independent of any derivative* (which may not even exist). And $x\mapsto x^3$ is strictly increasing on the whole of $\mathbb R$. Sorry, but your last sentence in the comment is not correct.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand why is it increasing when x = 0

Comment: Compare $f(0)$ with $f(\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ is slightly larger than $0$. What do you observe?

Comment: Well, it's increasing, right?

Comment: Ohh, I understood it now. The function is increasing but the derivative isn't positive at the origin, that's confusing, but makes sense. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I already upvoted it but I don't have 15 rep so it won't appear to everyone

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the converse is true. In geometric terms, $f'(x)$ denotes the slope of $f(x)$ at $x$. If the slope is positive, then the function is increasing. Note that $f'(x)$ can be decreasing, but still positive. This means that $f(x)$ is still increasing but is what we call *concave down*: that is, increasing more and more slowly.

Comment: How can f'(x) be decreasing while it still positive? it'd need the second derivative to be negative and in anyway consequentially f'(x) would become negative and so f(x)

Comment: *Positive* and *increasing* have different meanings. By positive we mean the y value is greater than zero. By increasing we mean the function has a positive slope.

Comment: Yep, I got that. But to match with the book's answer I would need an increasing y with a derivative that isn't positive.

Comment: See Hanno's answer. Let $y=x^3$. $y'$ is decreasing from negative infinity to zero while $y$ is increasing.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I got what you meant now, but still to agree with the book's answer I would need the derivative to be negative